# How to make QScrollArea working properly?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5

I am trying to add a number of labels into a `Qscrollarea`, but it is not working properly. I added a `Qwidget` into the scroll area, and added labels in that `Qwidget`. I added   `self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)`
Still it is not working.

This is (a part of)the file I created using Qtdesigner:

```py
self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.gridLayoutWidget)
self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 457, 428))
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
self.gridLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 441, 431))
self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_2")
self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
self.gridLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 1, 0, 1, 4)
```

And I used another file to run the program:

```py
for i in range(50) :
            self.ResultLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
            self.ResultLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 30))
            self.ResultLabel.setWordWrap(True)
            self.ResultLabel.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Segoe UI',9))
            self.ResultLabel.setText(str(i))
            self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.ResultLabel, i, 0, 1, 2)
```

This is what I get :

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a second subwidget (`gridLayoutWidget_2`)? That's completely unnecessary, just set the layout to the `scrollAreaWidgetContents`. Note that if you're using a file generated with `pyuic` you should *not* edit it, as those files should always be used as imported modules and **never** modified. Read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: I never edited the file generated by the pyuic. I just added the gridlayout into the scroll area in Designer. The name `gridLayoutWidget_2`  was generated by the Designer.

Comment: I never said that you did, but since you didn't provide a full [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (which you always should) I preferred to be clear about that, since it's a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an empty scroll area that will be filled by code, you don't have to add another widget into it from Designer, because it already exists, and that is `scrollAreaWidgetContents`.

Since that contents widget has no layout set when a scroll area is created, you have to set one on your own. You can do it manually from code:

```
    self.contentsLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
```

In the above case, remove the `gridLayoutWidget_2` from designer, as it's unnecessary.

Alternatively, you can also do the same from Designer with a small workaround:

- add any widget (a button, a label, it doesn't matter) to the scrollAreaWidgetContents widget; you actually already have such a widget (the `gridLayoutWidget_2` you created inside it), so you could use that for this purpose;
- right click on the scroll area and select grid layout from the "Lay out" sub menu;
- remove the widget added before (or the `gridLayoutWidget_2` in your case);

This is required because Designer doesn't allow to set a layout for a widget until it has at least one child widget.